# Playa Plug in - Slows down site to a crawl?

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic, performance

I have a site running playa module and it's painfully slow to run any queries.

Here is my tag code:

{exp:channel:entries channel="sous_sous_categorie" url_title="{segment_4}" dynamic="no"}

```
                    {if {exp:playa:total_parents}}
                        {if segment_2 != "nouveautes"}
                        <h1 class="rang">{embed="kanuk/.get_sous-sous-cat-lang" url_title="{url_title}"}</h1>
                        <div class="article">
                        {/if}
                            {exp:playa:parents channel="article" var_prefix="article"}

                                <?php $article_entry_id = "{article:entry_id}"; ?>

                                {article:categorie}                                     
                                    {if "{segment_2}" == "{article:url_title}"}                                 
                                            {embed="kanuk/.coat_render" last_entry_id="<?php echo $article_entry_id; ?>"}
                                    {/if}
                                {/article:categorie}
                            {/exp:playa:parents}

                            {if segment_2 != "nouveautes"}
                                </div><!-- END article -->
                            {/if}
                    {/if}

                {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Which loads:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="article" entry_id="{embed:last_entry_id}" dynamic="no"}
    {sous_categorie}
    {if "{url_title}" == "{segment_3}" || "{segment_3}" == ""}
    <div class="manteau" style="">
        {embed="kanuk/.coat_render2" last_entry_id="{embed:last_entry_id}"} 
    </div><!-- END manteau -->
    {/if}
    {/sous_categorie}       
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

which loads:

{exp:channel:entries channel="article" entry_id="{embed:last_entry_id}" dynamic="no"}
            
                {categorie}
                    {if title == "Nouveautés"}
                        
                    {/if}
                {/categorie}

```
                <ul class="couleurList">
                    {couleur_produit}                       
                    <li><div style="width:48px; height:30px; background-color:{swatch}" data-load="{couleur_{language_code}}" alt="{couleur_{language_code}}"></div></li>
                    {/couleur_produit}
                </ul>
            {images_produit cover_only="yes"}<img src="{image:url:medium}" width="220" height="280" alt="{title}">{/images_produit}
            <div class="manteauNom">{title}</div>

            <div class="manteauPrix">
                <div class="prixreg">
                    {if "{language_code}" == "en"}
                        ${prix_regulier}
                    {if:elseif "{language_code}" == "fr"}
                        {prix_regulier} $
                    {/if}
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Could you offer any hints / best practices to speed up page load time?

I'm convinced nesting these queries 3 layer deep is not helping but I don't know of another way of achieving my goal !

Comment: What types of fields are categorie and sous_categorie in this case? Are these playa fields? Also, could you elaborate a bit more on what the code is accomplishing?

Comment: @KaraTodd Categorie & sous_categorie are Playa Fields, Simply using these fields to establish product categories to create store hierarchy. See: http://kanuk.com/Collection/femmes/vetements-legers

Which is a live page of the code base I've include above !